# No module named fragbuilder, Import error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import

Past two days I am trying to solve one problem and I did every thing to resolve this problem. there is a package available. called "fragbuilder".

```
https://github.com/jensengroup/fragbuilder
```

I have used this package inside an Django Application.

As per the installation instruction I have installed this package.

```
How to use
1) Clone fragbuilder from this repository
git clone https://github.com/andersx/fragbuilder
2) Export the frabuilder directory to your PYTHONPATH eg:
export PYTHONPATH=/home/andersx/dev/fragbuilder:$PYTHONPATH
3) In your Python:
import fragbuilder
```

This method work for me and when I use my Django Application I am able to run this application successfully. But when I deploy this application on apache2 server either  with native or virtualenv python installation,  it shows error  like given bellow:

```
ImportError at /Pep_Des/
No module named fragbuilder
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://172.16.16.46/Pep_Des/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named fragbuilder
Exception Location: /home/jai/myproject/Peptide_Descriptor/dis_str_gen.py in <module>, line 4
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/jai/myproject',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoplotlib-0.3.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn_theano-0.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/progress-1.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geoplotlib-0.3.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/progress-1.3-py2.7.egg']
```

I have applied  the  knowledge which  I have gained throughout the python programming experience,  but unfortunately  nothing has worked for me.

Can any one guess the probable reason behind this  disgusting behaviour of python-path

**this my "000-default.conf" file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    Alias /static /home/jai/myproject/protocol/static
    <Directory /home/jai/myproject/protocol/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>



    <Directory /home/jai/myproject/pep_learn>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory> 


    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/jai/myproject:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    #
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jai/myproject/pep_learn/wsgi.py

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: did you install on fragbuilder on your Apache2 server?

Comment: Sorry but I din't get It what you want to ask. If you want to asked wither I have installed fragbuilder on my machine where apache2 is running then yes I have installed fragbuilder on my machine which is serving the Django application.